# Putting coding within a ListObject table

Tags: excel, vba

The below VBA code looks down column B in a table. When a value (60) is identified in Column B, I then copy the adjacent value from Column C into Column D.
I've tried doing an offset which works fine when not in a formal ListObject table, but I get an error message when within a table "invalid or unqualified reference".
How to I update the VBA code to work within an excel table?  I've searched around and tried a few changes but still getting errors.

```
Sub TableFind()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim rng As Range, C As Range

With Worksheet.ListObjects("myTable")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("B2:B" & LastRow)

        For Each C In rng
        If C.Value = "60" Then
            C.Offset(, 3).Copy
            C.Offset(, 4).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next C
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried to reference the table name after the `With Worksheet.ListObjects("myTable")`.  I tried doing similar before the range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to find the last row in a table; `DataBodyRange` refers to the body of the table so just work with that.

Assuming your table starts in column A, you could potentially do the following:

```
With Worksheet.ListObjects("myTable")
    For Each C in .ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange
        If C.Value = "60" Then
            C.Offset(, 2).Value = C.Offset(,1).Value
        End If
    Next C
End With
```